# Cannot manipulate cursor outside of render phase

Tags: clojurescript, om

Trying react for the first time, and I want to make a simple todo list app. But every time I press enter to trigger `onSubmit` it says `Uncaught Error: Cannot manipulate cursor outside of render phase, only om.core/transact!, om.core/update!, and cljs.core/deref operations allowed`. While I think this is a very good error message, I don't know what to do.

```
(ns app.core
  (:require [om.core :as om :include-macros true]
            [sablono.core :as html :refer-macros [html]]))

(def app-state (atom
                {:todos [{:todo "first"}
                         {:todo "second"}]
                 :current ""}))

(defn to-do
  [data]
  (om/component
   (html [:li (:todo data)])))

(defn to-dos
  [data]
  (om/component
   (html [:div
          [:form {:on-submit (fn [e]
                               (.preventDefault e)
                               (om/transact! data :todos (fn [v]
                                                           (js/console.log (:current data))
                                                           (conj v (:current data)))))}
           [:input {:type "text" 
                    :placeholder "Enter some text."
                    :on-change (fn [e] (om/update! data :current (.. e -target -value)))}]]
          [:ul 
          (om/build-all to-do (:todos data))]])))

(om/root to-dos app-state {:target js/document.body})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is where you access `data` inside om/transact! where you should operate on `v`:

`(:current v)` instead of `(:current data)`

or you may try `(:current @data)` for most recent value of data

Comment: Using `(:current v)` is much preferable to accessing the `@data` cursor again. There is a second problem here, though, with the `:todos` argument to `om/transcat!`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two issues with:

```
(om/transact! data :todos (fn [v]
  (js/console.log (:current data))
  (conj v (:current data)))))
```

One is what @edbond said above: you should use `(:current v)` rather than `(:current data)`. The other problem, however, is that you are specifying the `:todos` keyword, and instead, you should simply change `data` itself, since `:current` is outside of `:todos` in your app-state shown. So the correct formulation would be:

```
(om/transact! data (fn [v]
  (js/console.log (:current v))
  (conj v (:current v)))))
```